# Is my file unstructured or semi-structured data?

Tags: file, text, nlp, text-mining, dataformat

I am bit confused with my text file data format. 
I have text files with two sections like

```
main
about author


body
5 main different sentences about book.
```

I should consider my text files as unstructured or semi-structured. I think all text files are unstructured, but not sure. 
please suggest

thanks

Comment: The question is slightly unclear. What will be the length of `body` section? If you have a blank line separating each section, then i would say file contents are structured. If there is any keyword appearing before each section, then also file contents are structured. If you have specific format provided by the owner of the data, i would say the data is structured. You can call the data semi-structured if some portion of the file content is structured but others part are not. Note that when i said structured file content, i meant that you can identify specific section of information from the f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structured, unstructured and semi-structured data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748240/structured-unstructured-and-semi-structured-data)